# How to show text with icon for item from ActionBar?

Tags: android

There is the following menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:title="Text111" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

As you can see I set icon, title and "showAsAction" attribute for my menu item, but there is only icon on Actionbar when I execute it. How can I fix it?

Comment: When you execute what? Please try to be more clear.

Comment: I've added this menu to my Android project and executed this project

Comment: try to reduce your image size(width and height) because I think your text can be below of that image and image can be consume more size in menu so that you can not see it in your device or emulator

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:title="Text111" android:showAsAction="withText"/>
</menu>
```

check back your code , test with ic_launcher first .and move ifRoom to check if its the cause or no!.